# Get new HSL Color by lumMod/lumOff

Tags: rgb, hsl, luminance

Am I doing this correctly?
For example, I have an `RGB(165,165,165)` and convert it to the HSL(Get (0, 0, 64.7)).
Actually I parse xml, and there I have two parameters lumMod = '60 000' and lumOff = '40 000' (As I know it means that I must multiply the L component by 0.6 and then add 0.4 to the L component)

Okey `new_l = 0.647*0.6 + 0.4 = 0.7882`

And now I convert back from HSL(0, 0, 78.8) to `RGB(198, 198, 198)`

Actually I need get RGB(183,183,183). Because it's right answer. Where I was wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you think `RGB(183,183,183)` is the right answer with `lumMod val="60000"` and `lumOff val="40000"`. With those values and an input of `RGB(165,165,165)`, the correct return value is actually `RGB(201,201,201)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all night debugging I have been founded answer for my question.

Thanks to King Salemno from [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb151eb0-e539-4f12-a453-1ff46dc28578/satmod-satoff-documentation?forum=os_openXML-ecma) topic

> The algorithm the charts are performing, the following steps are
>   performed:
>
> 1. Obtain RGB of the base color they’re interested in (e.g. Accent 3)
> 2. Convert to HSL
> 3. Multiply the L component by lumMod
> 4. Add lumOff to the L component
> 5. Convert back to RGB
>
> The same logic also applies to satMod, satOff, hueMod, & hueOff.

But for rgb-color, which have only one value for all levels (like as (255, 255, 255) or (123, 123, 123)) I change lumMod to `lumMod = lumMod - 0.04(+-0.005)` and do the same for lumoff parameter.

So if I have RGB(165,165,165) and convert it to the HSL(0, 0, 0.647).
After I change `HSL.L = HSL.L*(lumMod - 0.04) + (lumOff - 0.04) = 0.718`
And now I convert back from HSL(0, 0, 0.718) to RGB(183,183,183)

I don't know why it work like this, but it work. I tried to find out it.